# QProcess to extract file using 7zip as subprocess

Tags: c++, qt, 7zip, qprocess

I have a use case in an application using C++ and Qt (on windows 10). The application uses 7zip.exe as a subprocess to uncompress the files in a selected folder. I need to use QProcess to extract files.

The code I came up with is as shown below.

```
     MainWindow.h
QStringList zipFiles;
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_browseButton_clicked()
{
        directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this);
        if(recursiveOperation){
            QDirIterator it(directory.canonicalPath(), QStringList() << "*.zip" <<  "*.7z", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
             ui->outputLogResultList->addItem("File selected to uncompress");
             ui->outputLogResultList->addItem("-----------------------------");
            while (it.hasNext()){
                QString file = it.next();
                ui->outputLogResultList->addItem(file);
                zipFilesWithRecursion.append(file);
            }

        }else{
            zipFilesWithoutRecursion = directory.entryList(QStringList() << "*.zip"<< "*.7z", QDir::Files);
            qDebug() << zipFilesWithoutRecursion;

            foreach(QString filename4, zipFilesWithoutRecursion) {
                     qDebug() << "inside loop";
                    zipFilesWithCompletePath.append( QString(directory.canonicalPath()+"/%1").arg(filename4));
                }



                qDebug() << "without recursion";
                qDebug() << zipFilesWithCompletePath;
        }
}



void MainWindow::unZipFile()
{
    int numberOfFiles;
    if(recursiveOperation){
        numberOfFiles = zipFilesWithRecursion.size();
        foreach(QString filename3, zipFilesWithRecursion) {
            QStringList queryArguments;
            queryArguments << "x";
                  qDebug() << filename3;
                  queryArguments <<""""+ filename3+ """";
                  queryArguments << "-o"+directory.canonicalPath()+"/output"+QString().setNum(numberOfFiles);
                  qDebug() << queryArguments;
                  unZip.setWorkingDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
                  unZip.start("7za.exe", queryArguments);
                  numberOfFiles--;
              }
        numberOfFiles = 0;
    }else{
        numberOfFiles = zipFilesWithCompletePath.size();
        foreach(QString filename3, zipFilesWithCompletePath) {
            QStringList queryArguments;
            queryArguments << "x";
                  qDebug() << filename3;
                  queryArguments <<""""+ filename3+ """";
                  queryArguments << "-o"+directory.canonicalPath()+"/output"+QString().setNum(numberOfFiles);
                  qDebug() << queryArguments;
                  unZip.setWorkingDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
                  unZip.start("7za.exe", queryArguments);
                  numberOfFiles--;
              }
        numberOfFiles = 0;
    }


}
```

The code run correctly, but after processing the first file, it does not process any other files and displays the state saying "QProcess::start: Process is already running"
The output segment is as follows.

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen DPI.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
("SemiFinal.zip", "temata_vskp_-_podklady_pro_zadani_vskp(10).zip")
inside loop
inside loop
without recursion
("F:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/SemiFinal.zip", "F:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/temata_vskp_-_podklady_pro_zadani_vskp(10).zip")
"F:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/SemiFinal.zip"
("x", "F:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/SemiFinal.zip", "-oF:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/output2")
"F:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/temata_vskp_-_podklady_pro_zadani_vskp(10).zip"
("x", "F:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/temata_vskp_-_podklady_pro_zadani_vskp(10).zip", "-oF:/taskPractiseDirectoryForQt/output1")
QProcess::start: Process is already running
```

The folder has 2 .zip files, My question is why second file is not getting processed.

Comment: You stated your requirement, but what is your actual *question*?

Comment: In any case, `""""` doesn't do what you think, use `"\""` or `"\x22"` instead. Also, `queryArguments << """" + directory.canonicalPath()+ """"; queryArguments << "/*.zip";` should probably be more like `queryArguments << "\"" + directory.canonicalPath() + "/*.zip\"";` instead.

Comment: `unZip.setWorkingDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());` may not be the location you want for the working directory. Did you check your executable's folder to see if may files were extracted in that folder?

Comment: Yes, I placed the 7za.exe in application directory(where my .pro file is present).

Comment: What I am saying is I believe the working directory is the folder that 7z will attempt to extract your files.

Comment: One more thing the QStringList zipFiles seems to be empty in unZipFile() funciton

Comment: That would be a bug. Use your debugger to make sure it is not empty. My advice is to debug the on_browseButton_clicked() function.

Comment: I check no files are present in folder with 7za.exe .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244269/discussion-between-syed-iftekharuddin-and-drescherjm).

Comment: @drescherjm please have a look at the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for your QProcess (unZip) to finish, before processing next file or create QProcess instances per file in cycles `foreach(QString filename3, zipFilesWithCompletePath)` in `void MainWindow::unZipFile()` method to process them concurrently.
If you try to wait `unZip.waitForFinished()`, your application would be unresponsive for that time as it's main thread would be suspened till process finished.
If you want to process files concurrently, QProcess instances should be created in heap, e.g. `auto unZipFileProcess = new QProcess(this);` and you'll need to write some code to control started processes and wait them all for finish before you close your application, because in that case all processes would be interrupted and killed by their decstructors. To control process state it's proper to connect to QProcess instance signals - `errorOccurred` and `finished`. Also these signals should be connected to QProcess' `deleteLater` slot to avoid memory growth. At this moment you would not need your `unZip` static or member variable (i don't know how it is declared) at all.
In another way, if you do not need to track files processing (wait for finished, report process errors and so on), you can to start processes as detached with static `QProcess::startDetached` method and not create any QProcess instance at all. So you would not need to control them and synchronize them with your application lifetime.
And you defenetly need to redesign your `MainWindow::unZipFile()` method to avoid code repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexey suggested I used

```
unZip.waitForFinished(3000);
```

before the end of loop and it worked for me.

Comment: It depends of time, that is really needed to process each file, and can cause error to appear if process is not complete in 3 seconds. This solution is not good. I suggest you to process files concurrently. You even can to start processes as detached with static `QProcess::startDetached` method and not create QProcess instances at all. So you would not need to control them and synchronize them with your application lifetime.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, Thanks